# Bootstrap 3 Carousel tweaking

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

When I was working in Bootstrap 2.x.x, it would have added a script like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $.supersized({

            // Functionality
            slide_interval          :   4000,       // Length between transitions
            transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition
            new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
            performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)                                        
            image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

            // Components                           
            slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images

                                        <?php echo implode(',', $newarray) ?>
                                        ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

is this still possible in Bootstrap 3?

Also, I'm looking to have the slideshow redirect to another page after the last slide is played. So I was wondering how I might go about doing that.

Comment: This should have nothing to do with Bootstrap, since you're using a [separate jQuery plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/). Have you *tried* using it in Bootstrap 3 yet? If so, what specific problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3's carousel, and from what I remember of bootstrap 2.x.x it would have this <script> on the page of the slider. I know this particular one isn't bootstrap, but it looked similar. I'm looking to make tweaks like I mentioned before, where after the last slide plays, it will go to another page and have the control to be able to do things like, interval times and whether the slide show will autoplay.

Comment: That is *not* how you call [Bootstrap's Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel). Start with those docs, try a few things, and let us know when you have a specific problem with the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there just aren't as many.

```
$('.yourCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 5000, // The amount of time in between slides
  pause: “hover”, // 'hover' or 'false'
  wrap: true // Whether the carousel should cycle continuously or have hard stops
});
```

Comment: is there something I can put here that'll tell it to go to another page once the last slide plays?

Comment: Not easily. There are no methods to hook into that fire after all slides play. Also, programmatically opening new pages is tricky as well. The TB carousel is very basic so if you need extended functionality, I would take a look at other sliders. There's plenty out there.